# Advice on transfering data from one db to another, syntax

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL Server. I have done basic admin, backups etc. I have also spent 2 years doing MySQL for a software company offering software support for their MySQL bespoke program. I'm mainly a tech guy (desktop, Networking) but getting my head round this DB stuff!

I have started with a company that run SQL Server 2005 and need some stuff doing, and I am struggling with the syntax more than anything. The company have 4 SQL Servers running the same db's (program wise) for 4 differing locations.

What I am trying to do is copy the updated cost price list from table 1 to the other tables with * criteria. Basically copy `table.parts` from `server1.parts` to `server2.parts * currencyconvertion field * markup (%)`

That bit seems to be quite easy except I cannot get the db's to link. I enter the server name which contains - and the syntax says wrong eg `uk-server1 'can't find 'uk'`? Also I am unsure in the 4 part address is correct servername, dbname, schema, table?

Right ok. Previously when tried I was unable to link the two servers. I have now resolved this and the server is now linked. I have been told that maybe there is a need for [] to quote'' server name. I have tried this with no success. The problem seems to be the name of the server having a - uk-efacs. as soon as I type this and remember it is now linked the herror is can't find server efacs an uk is wrong?? It's not ready the full server name? WHY?

Figured this out by trial and error just needs [] by server name ie [uk-efacs].db.table.field. This now is ok just need to work on my syntax as the query shows errors.

Comment: Please post the commands you've tried and errors you get

Comment: use traindb
go
update partmaster
set partmaster.fsunit = uk-efacs.efacsdb.partmaster.fsunit * uk-efacs.efacsdb.currency.currate * 1.32

Comment: This is the errors Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'uk'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "efacs.efacsdb.partmaster.fsunit" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'uk'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "efacs.efacsdb.currency.currate" could not be bound.

Comment: It's preferrable to edit the question. I can't help with your problem, but it will be easier for other people to read it

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Linked Server record on the server you're running this from. In Object Explorer (in SSMS) expand Server Objects, right click Linked Servers and select new. Select SQL Server and type the name of your remote server and then try your query again. Bit puzzled as the snippet you provided

```
update partmaster 
set partmaster.fsunit = uk-efacs.efacsdb.partmaster.fsunit * uk-efacs.efacsdb.currency.currate * 1.32
```

Seems to parse just fine.